# can Not use the button to Manually turn On traction control (TRAC) in my Toyoto Corolla 2016

Tags: traction-control, stability

I live in Toronto, Canada, and we change our regular season tires to winter tires when winter arrives.

I took my Toyoto Corolla 2016 car to a mechanic in order to change the tires.

After I got the car back, and started the engine, I noticed that the “TRAC OFF” indicator was lighting up.

In my Toyota Corolla 2016, I have a single button that can turn both the “TRAC” and “VSC” on or off.

From what I read online, it seems that TRAC will turn back On if you accelerate up past the 25-30 mph speeds

However, when I reduced the speed down to less than 25mph, the TRAC turns off.

If I press the button for 3 seconds, I can toggles between VSC on and off.  Unfortunately, it does Not affect the TRAC

The Only time TRAC turns on is when I accelerate up past the 25-30 mph speeds.

Essentially, I can Not use the button to Manually turn on traction control (TRAC) in my Toyoto Corolla 2016

Do you think the mechanic may have mistakenly damaged something or unintentionally done something to affect the TRAC system?  If yes, could someone please elaborate on the steps that can be taken to resolve said problem?

Comment: Have you asked if the mechanic changed any settings?

Comment: I went back to the mechanic autoshop, and he suggested that I drive around for a while.  As one drives, he thought the sensors would start functioning again, and the TRAC would work as expected again.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have a 2016 corolla s ,I also had my tire changed N alignment done same issue came back abs an traction both on took it in 3 times finally I broke down an went to toyota it cost me 100 bucks to have them calibrate my steering an that solved my issue . Most places don't have the proper computers to complete the work right .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).